# go install in golang not creating sub package archives

Tags: go

I have created a package named go-orm in golang and its structure is follows.

```
go-orm
--| mine.go
--| src
-----| src.go
-----| db
--------| DBConnection.go
```

When I ran the command "go install" in go-orm directory, it created only
go-orm.a but not src.a and db.a (sub directories or packages). When I checked 
"go install" with mgo package it created .a files for it's sub directory "bson".

I need the same functionality for my package. What change is needed in my
package to make this possible.

### Edit 1

my package is in GOPATH/src/ directory. All my sub packages(src and db) exist.

Comment: Does `DBConnection.go` starts with "`package go-orm/src/db`"? Does your `$GOPATH` environment variable references `/path/to`, with `src/go-orm` folder immediately in it? And your .a are generated in `$GOPATH/pkg/<arch>/go-orm`?

Comment: I got go-orm.a in $GOPATH/pkg/<arch>. But archives for sub packages like src and db are not created. When the end user runs "go get mypackage_path" then I need all archives (go-orm.a, src.a and db.a) for my package to work properly.

Comment: Then lets check how your sources are organized. Are your sources in `$GOPATH/src/go-orm`? Could you answer my initial questions about `DBConnection.go`? Does the folder `$GOPATH/src/go-orm/src/db` exist?

Comment: my DBConnection.go starts with "package db" and not "package go-orm/src/db". "package go-orm/src/db" is not allowed. we can't specify path there. I updated my question for your other questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
After long analysis I found that "import" statement in root directory go file
```

can do the trick. I created one extra file named create_archieve.go in root 
directory(go-orm). Inside that I just inserted the following lines which created
go-orm.a, src.a and db.a.

### create_archieve.go

package nosql_orm

import _"go-orm/src/db"

Answer (score 2):

> [Package build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> Go Path
>
> The Go path is a list of directory trees containing Go source code. It
>   is consulted to resolve imports that cannot be found in the standard
>   Go tree. The default path is the value of the GOPATH environment
>   variable, interpreted as a path list appropriate to the operating
>   system (on Unix, the variable is a colon-separated string; on Windows,
>   a semicolon-separated string; on Plan 9, a list).
>
> Each directory listed in the Go path must have a prescribed structure:
>
> The src/ directory holds source code. The path below 'src' determines
>   the import path or executable name.
>
> The pkg/ directory holds installed package objects. As in the Go tree,
>   each target operating system and architecture pair has its own
>   subdirectory of pkg (pkg/GOOS_GOARCH).
>
> If DIR is a directory listed in the Go path, a package with source in
>   DIR/src/foo/bar can be imported as "foo/bar" and has its compiled form
>   installed to "DIR/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/foo/bar.a" (or, for gccgo,
>   "DIR/pkg/gccgo/foo/libbar.a").
>
> The bin/ directory holds compiled commands. Each command is named for
>   its source directory, but only using the final element, not the entire
>   path. That is, the command with source in DIR/src/foo/quux is
>   installed into DIR/bin/quux, not DIR/bin/foo/quux. The foo/ is
>   stripped so that you can add DIR/bin to your PATH to get at the
>   installed commands.
>
> Here's an example directory layout:
>
> GOPATH=/home/user/gocode
>
> ```
> /home/user/gocode/
>     src/
>         foo/
>             bar/               (go code in package bar)
>                 x.go
>             quux/              (go code in package main)
>                 y.go
>     bin/
>         quux                   (installed command)
>     pkg/
>         linux_amd64/
>             foo/
>                 bar.a          (installed package object)
> ```

Use the prescribed directory structure, including the use of `src` as a directory name. Follow the example. Don't use `src`, `pkg`, or `bin` as package names.

```
go-orm
--| mine.go
--| src     <== !? Don't use src as a package name.
-----| src.go
-----| db
--------| DBConnection.go
```